# Creating a WebService in Java with JCO3

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat7, jco

Hi people im trying to implement a webService in java wich uses JCO3 library.

i have exported as a WAR into webapps FOLDER on a server, but when i try tu run on a Server(Tomcat 7) on windows 7 32 bits.

It's a web dynamic project.
And i use a sap library called (sapjco3.jar, this jar brings a sapjco3.dll).
and also a json-simple-1.1.1.jar.

appears the nexts error:

```
INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
    oct 10, 2014 2:30:34 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextInitialized
INFORMACIÓN: WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing
    oct 10, 2014 2:30:34 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextInitialized
GRAVE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/conn/jco/AbapException
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/conn/jco/AbapException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.getImplementorClass(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:528)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:207)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:133)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.conn.jco.AbapException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        ... 15 more

oct 10, 2014 2:30:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart GRAVE: Excepción enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de clase com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/conn/jco/AbapException    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:107)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/conn/jco/AbapException   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.getImplementorClass(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:528)    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:207)  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:133)  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:97)  ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.conn.jco.AbapException  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)  at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)  ... 15 more

oct 10, 2014 2:30:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal GRAVE: Error listenerStart oct 10, 2014 2:30:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal GRAVE: Falló en arranque del Contexto [/middleware_ws] debido a errores previos oct 10, 2014 2:30:34 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextDestroyed INFORMACIÓN: WSSERVLET13: JAX-WS context listener destroyed oct 10, 2014 2:30:35 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener contextInitialized INFORMACIÓN: WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing oct 10, 2014 2:30:36 PM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate <init> INFORMACIÓN: WSSERVLET14: JAX-WS servlet initializing oct 10, 2014 2:30:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] oct 10, 2014 2:30:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] oct 10, 2014 2:30:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFORMACIÓN: Server startup in 3489 ms
```

This app works fine when i run as a JAVA APPLICATION.

i HOPE YOR HELP
Regards

Answer (score 0):

When using eclipse to build a war file, be sure to have all required runtime libraries and project dependencies in the "Deployment Assemblies" (Project Properties).

For Dynamic Web Projects the class path is only used to compile your source code. The deployment assemblies will be packed as jar files into the WEB-INF/lib folder inside your WAR-File.

Comment: i use a sap library called sapjco3.jar and also a json-simple-1.1.1.jar.